# Html input within Javascript will not post

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, session

I have a form that I will be filled out and stored. There are two files. The first file with the form in html and javascript, the second results2.php file to process this form and store into database. All html inputs outside of the javascript store correctly with the correct names $name = $_POST['name'] and $date = $_POST['date']; However the issue is that , input name="jobnbr" within the javascript will not post even though I named the input as follows $jobno = $_POST['jobnbr'];. I hope this makes since~! Is there something missing? Thanks.

I also have this in results2.php:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO t_sessions (user_name, user_date, job_num) VALUES ('$name', '$date', '$jobno')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
for(var i=1; i<11; i++){
  var html = ''
  +'  <tr style="background:#eee;">'
  +'    <td><u>'+i+'</u></td>'
  +'   <td><input name="jobnbr" value=""></td>'
  +'    <td><input name="start_hr'+i+'" value="00" class="t1" onchange="if(!this.init) this.init=1; return calc(this)" accesskey="'+i+'"> :'
  +'        <input name="start_min'+i+'" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)"> '
  +'        <select name="start_time'+i+'" onchange="return calc(this)">'
  +'        <option>AM<option>PM'
  +'        </select>'
  +'    </td>'
  +'    <td><input name="end_hr'+i+'" value="00" class="t1" onchange="if(!this.init){ this.init=1; this.form.end_time'+i+'.options.selectedIndex=1; }; return calc(this)"> :'
  +'        <input name="end_min'+i+'" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)"> '
  +'        <select name="end_time'+i+'" onchange="return calc(this)">'
  +'        <option>AM<option>PM'
  +'        </select>'
  +'    </td>'
  +'    <td><input name="break_hr'+i+'" value="00" class="t1" style="display:none; position: absolute" onchange="return calc(this)"> '
  +'     <select name="code'+i+'" onchange="return calc(this)">'
  +'        <option>Choose your option<option>'
  +'   <option value="Drilling">1. Drilling</option>'
  +'   <option value="Development">2. Development</option>'
  +'   <option value="Moving/Set-up">3. Moving/Set-up</option>'
  +'   <option value="Travel">4. Travel</option>'
  +'   <option value="Maintenance">5. Maintenance</option>'
  +'   <option value="Shop Time">6. Shop Time</option>'
  +'   <option value="Training">7. Training</option>'
  +'   <option value="Other">8. Other</option>'
  +'   <option value="Drilling/Development">A. Drilling/Development</option>'
  +'   <option value="Pump Install/Test Pump">B. Pump Install/Test Pump</option>'
  +'   <option value="Operator">C. Operator</option>'
  +'   <option value="Laborer">D. Laborer</option>'
  +'   <option value="Video/Inspection">E. Video/Inspection</option>'
  +'   <option value="Abandonment">F. Abandonment</option>'
  +'   <option value="Other">G. Other</option>'
  +'        <input name="break_min'+i+'" value="00" class="t1" style="display:none; position: absolute" onchange="return calc(this)"> '
  +'    </td>'
  +'   <td><input name ="descr"></td>'
  +'    <td><div id="stot'+i+'"></div></td>'
  +'  </tr>'
  
  document.write(html)
}


//--></script>
```

```html
<form name="sampleForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="results2.php">
 
<!-- start: content -->
  
  
   <div class="formSig">
   <div class="sigSPC">Name<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['u_first'])){
    echo "{$_SESSION['u_first']}";
 echo " ";
 echo "{$_SESSION['u_last']}";
} ?>"></div>
  <div class="sigSPC"><p>Date<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" value""></p></div>
   <div></div>
  </div><!---formSig--->
    
    
    
    <button class="button" formaction="includes/results2.php" name="submit" value="Find Difference">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: How are you getting the result of the JavaScript into the form?

Comment: I don't understand how that JavaScript loop is related to the HTML for the static part of the form.

Comment: Since you're creating the form with PHP, why don't you just put the loop in PHP as well, rather than JS?

Comment: @Barmar It's for a timecard so the JavaScript portion auto calculates the hours the user enters. I guess the only relation would be that all of the information will just need to be saved/ stored at once.

Comment: Where is it doing that? All it's doing is writing a bunch of table rows in a loop. It's not calculating anything.

Comment: Are you talking about `onchange="return calc(this)"`? That's not what I'm asking about. I want to know how this loop is writing its output into the `<form name="sampleform">`. And since it's writing `<tr>` elements, they need to be inside a `<table>`.

Comment: You should stop using `document.write()`. Use DOM methods to add to the `innerHTML` of an element.

Comment: The HTML that you're creating with JavaScript has to be inside the `<form>` if you want it to post.

Comment: @Barmar So, the JavaScript is before the closing </form> tag. Also, there is a script to get the form to auto calculate as well. Just trying to figure out if you can post an input that comes from the html within the JavaScript the same way. The form started out in .php but later decided to include the functionality shown in JavaScript and ran into this issue ha!

Comment: Where is the `<table>` that surrounds the `<tr>` that the JavaScript prints?

Comment: Another issue: all your `name` attributes in the loop need to have `+i`, so you need `name="jobnbr'+i+'"`. But a better method is to use names that end in `[]`. Then the corresponding `$_POST` element will be an array of all those inputs.